# Win7 with wireless bluetooth headphones Shure SE215: what could cause the white noise?

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I bought a used Shure SE215 and paired it with my laptop (Win7 64) via bluetooth.

There is a bit of white noise / hiss on the background every time the headphones receive audio or "wait" for the audio signal to come (no noise on "idle" mode). Its especially annoying when I listen for some speech / lecture: there you hear it clearly.

Is there anything I could do about it?

Comment: Maybe some sort of Bluetooth radio interference? Does it do it with wired headphones?

Comment: I tried with a smartphone, same thing: power on -> white noise

Comment: most likely is being generated by the headphone amplifier.

Comment: As @Moab implies, automatic gain (or volume) control (AGC or AVC) increases gain when the audio input is low, amplifying electrical noise.

Comment: The problem is that it’s audible and annoying on any more or less quiet video

Comment: @lim-lim If it happens independently of the device it is connected then it's a problem of the headphones and your question is off-topic.